I.........you something to drink and come back immediately. (future)
Context: My friend comes over to my house, I lead her to the living room. Here is the conversation:

Me: Have a seat here.
My friend: (Taking her seat)
Me: I......................... you something to drink and come back immediately.
My friend: oh, thank you so much.

(1) I will make you something…
(2) I am making you something …
(3) I am going to make you something …
(4) I will be making you something …
I can use all of them. Right?
I think that there is not much difference. Right?

"I'll be right back" is far more idiomatic in your context than "come back immediately".

You cannot use the "making" versions when coordinating with " and come back". It would have to be "coming" or "will come".

@TimR thank you for your correction on "and come back". I would like to ask about the first part of the sentence too.

The first one is by far the most natural, if you are going straight to the kitchen to do it. In particular, I will be making sounds like a plan for the future. "I will be making hot drinks at 3.30, but would anyone like some water now?"

I would delete  the subordinate clause “come back immediately”. It adds nothing and is redundant. With that in mind, all your versions are grammatical and plausible ways to make an offer. However, sentences 1, 2 and 3 are the most natural. And I would argue the majority of native speakers would use contractions in speech.

I'll make you something to drink.
I'm making you something to drink.
I'm gonna make you something to drink.

As the numerous comments below testify, "gonna" is a nonstandard spelling (a contraction) of two words going to. Thus the full form  “I am going to…” is preferred in more formal communication.

I am going to make you something to drink

I will be making you something to drink.


This is grammatical but suggests that the speaker will prepare the beverage at some point in the future, which would contradict the subordinate clause “come back immediately.” It's like saying you will be fixing a cocktail at 5 o'clock in a different room, but you will be back immediately. Even if it was a glass of soda or water, and the speaker had to go to the kitchen, it won't be prepared at this specific moment.  Again, sentence 4 is grammatical but it lacks spontaneity to my ears.
In an English test, I would suggest the student choose the "shall" form (if it is an option) as that is often used for making polite offers; e.g.

"Shall I make you a cup of tea?"


“I'll make (you) a nice cup of tea”

This is less formal, but also acceptable in writing and the form I would naturally choose. It suggests that the speaker made the decision there and then whereas "I'm making you a nice cup of tea” would suggest the speaker had already decided to put the kettle on when she knew her friend would be visiting.
